# Identify ID in function JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a table that I generate with a "while" php cicle. The table in the DB has a Primary Key, that I would use to UPDATE the data in the database with JQUERY and AJAX:

The structure of the table in php is:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><textarea name="iD_Orsyp1" id="iD_Orsyp1" value="1">1</textarea></td>
  <td><textarea name="Sistema1" id="Sistema1" value="Orsyp">Orsyp</textarea></td>
  <td><textarea name="Azione_Intrapresa1" id="Azione_Intrapresa1" onkeyup="UpdateRun()"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><textarea name="iD_Orsyp2" id="iD_Orsyp2" value="2">2</textarea></td>
  <td><textarea name="Sistema2" id="Sistema2" value="Orsyp">Orsyp</textarea></td>
  <td><textarea name="Azione_Intrapresa2" id="Azione_Intrapresa2" onkeyup="UpdateRun()"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Where iD_Orsyp is the primaryKey. I use ONKEYUP to call the update function.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function UpdateRun(){

      **var id =  $('#iD_Orsyp1').val();**
      var Sistema = $('#Sistema'+id).val();
      var Azione_Intrapresa = $('#Azione_Intrapresa'+id).val();


      $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       //url:'UpdateRunbook.php',
       data: {ajax: 1,Azione_Intrapresa: Azione_Intrapresa, iD_Orsyp: id,Sistema:Sistema},
       success: function(response){
    console.log(Azione_Intrapresa);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(Sistema);


        //$('#response').text('Azione_Intrapresa: ' + response);
        //alert($("input:checkbox:checked").val());
        //$('#response').text('name : ' + response);


       }
      });
    }
</script>
```

In this case I set the ID of the TextArea static "iD_Orsyp1" and "iD_Orsyp2". How can I take the id when iD_Orsyp* is set by the while cicle?

Comment: Making an Ajax call for every keypress seems like a bad idea.

Comment: you could simply insert the id into the function params the same way you're inserting it into the textarea's ID attribute. This whole setup though seems messy.

Answer (score 1):

Consider passing the `event` parameter. This way you can use `event.target` as the element or as a jQuery Object, `$(event.target)`.

```js
$(function() {
  function UpdateRun(event) {
    var id = $(event.target).data("key");
    var Sistema = $('#Sistema' + id).val();
    var Azione_Intrapresa = $('#Azione_Intrapresa' + id).val();

    console.log(id, Sistema, Azione_Intrapresa);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      //url:'UpdateRunbook.php',
      data: {
        ajax: 1,
        Azione_Intrapresa: Azione_Intrapresa,
        iD_Orsyp: id,
        Sistema: Sistema
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(Azione_Intrapresa);
        console.log(id);
        console.log(Sistema);


        //$('#response').text('Azione_Intrapresa: ' + response);
        //alert($("input:checkbox:checked").val());
        //$('#response').text('name : ' + response);


      }
    });
  }

  $("textarea[id^='Azione_Intrapresa']").keyup(UpdateRun);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><textarea name="iD_Orsyp1" id="iD_Orsyp1" value="1">1</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea name="Sistema1" id="Sistema1" value="Orsyp">Orsyp</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea name="Azione_Intrapresa1" id="Azione_Intrapresa1" data-key="1"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><textarea name="iD_Orsyp2" id="iD_Orsyp2" value="2">2</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea name="Sistema2" id="Sistema2" value="Orsyp">Orsyp</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea name="Azione_Intrapresa2" id="Azione_Intrapresa2" data-key="2"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I also added the `data-key` attribute, that you can populate from PHP with the Unique ID.